# Continue execution of a Python update script without waiting for user input

Tags: python, linux, sys

I have written a simple script to carry out all my system updates and clean up on my Fedora 19 machine in one go:

```
import os

os.system('clear') # clear the terminal screen

os.system('yum -y update') # update the system without asking for confirmation

os.system('package-cleanup --oldkernels') 

os.system('package-cleanup --problems')

os.system('package-cleanup --dupes')

os.system('yum clean all')

exit()
```

The only issue is that in case there are old kernels to remove, the system will ask for user confirmation. How can I code this into the script, to automatically remove the old kernels without waiting for user confirmation?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you aren't using bash?

Comment: @yuvi: No, sudo is needed for update anyway. But that will not prevent the confirmation.

Comment: @Jayanth I've just gotten into programming, about 6 months now. I'm trying a little bit of this and that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run package-cleanup with '-y' too.

```
package-cleanup -y --oldkernels
```

Comment: @RoyalOats if Jayanth's answer helped you, please consider marking it as correct